# Debug / Show queries of SQLite (System.Data.SQLite) when used as provider for Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework, sqlite, debugging, ado.net, system.data.sqlite

I use Microsoft Entity Framework with a SQLite Database. I am having a really hard time when it comes to debugging.

Right now I only get this in my Output Windows after I called the "saveChanges()"-Method

```
SQLite error (1): near "SELECT": syntax error
```

**Apparently EF messed up some Query while Updating my data. I am looking for a way to get the query, that seems to be faulty. Can't I listen what queries get fired against the DB?**

I tried other things, which also did not provide more useful information:

- In the Stack Trace window it just says [External Code]
- I downloaded all symbols from Microsoft Symbol Server, but no more information there
- I put a BreakPoint right before "SaveChanges()" and steped through everything using F11, but no internal code (like from symbol files) is shown
- I downloaded source files of SQLite and included those projects into mine and compiled the source files. But it still doesn't step through the SQLite sources. I can see them in ObjectExplorer, but when I set BreakPoint there, they are not fully red (Breakpoint doesn't get reached. No symbols to this document are loaded)
- When examining the System.Data.UpdateException I find the stack trace which referes to a class of the SQLite Package, but since I can't set break points there, I can't read the parameter values there. This is the stacktrce:

> bei System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.Prepare(SQLiteConnection cnn, String
>   strSql, SQLiteStatement previous, UInt32 timeoutMS, String& strRemain)
>          bei System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.BuildNextCommand()
>          bei System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.GetStatement(Int32 index)
>          bei System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader.NextResult()
>          bei System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader..ctor(SQLiteCommand cmd, CommandBehavior behave)
>          bei System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior)
>          bei System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior)
>          bei System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>          bei System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.DynamicUpdateCommand.Execute(UpdateTranslator
>   translator, EntityConnection connection, Dictionary`2
>   identifierValues, List`1 generatedValues)
>          bei System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update(IEntityStateManager
>   stateManager, IEntityAdapter adapter)

- In one related SO-Question the answer was to look at the StateEntries, but as you can see here. They don't help me either.

[image]

Comment: For queries you can try using `.ToString()` or `.ToSqlString()` (depending on whether you are using ObjectQuery or DbQuery)

Comment: I am not using any queries. EF does everything for me.

Comment: If I understand correctly you want to see the queries EF created for you and for this you can use `.ToString()` or `.ToSqlString()`. Note that you cannot see UPDATE/DELETE statements created this way since they are generated inside SaveChanges.

Comment: My problem is that I never see any queries, because I let EF do everything (as you say generated inside). I don't create queries manually. However, I look for a way to see those inside generated queries. I am also fine with a solution outside VS2010. Like something that tracks all the DB-Usage between my application and the DB.

Comment: Are you talking about queries or updates/deletes? EF cannot come up with queries on it's kown. You need to write a query using - for instance - Linq. When you do that you can do `ToString()` or `ToSqlString` (e.g. `var c = from c in myDbContext.Customers; Write(c.ToString());)`. For updates and deletes you cannot do that and may try using IntelliTrace.

Comment: I am talking about all CRUD methods EF provides me. Like, I do `Cars myCars = db.Cars` which probably gets translated into `SELECT * FROM Cars`(compared to this video at 12:35 http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BS6IKdUd2V8). Now I want to see all queries that EF fires against my SQLite Database using System.Data.SQLite. Thanks for the tip with IntelliTrace. I will look into that.

Comment: I am talking about `db.Cars.ToString()` (given that db is `DbContext` if it is `ObjectContext` use `.ToSqlString()`) - it should get you the sql. Since you asked about debugging this + IntelliTrace should be fine. If you actually want to trace/log then there is not an easy way to do it but you could try using the tracing provider http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/EFProviderWrappers-c0b88f32 - I am not sure if you would have to adapt it to SqlLight though. For DbContext you may want to look at my post http://blog.3d-logic.com/2012/03/31/using-tracing-and-caching-provider-wrappers-with-codefirst/

Comment: Oh Ok. I didn't know about the usefulness of the ToString() Methods. Thanks! I'm gonna try them when I get back to work. And when doing Update/Inserts/Deletes, there is no SaveChanges().ToSqlString() or any related method, right?

Comment: No because in most cases there is no single command and there is no query and there is no API to get this information which is created and used deep in the stack. Therefore for these you should try the IntelliTrace.

Comment: For ObjectQuery it is supposed to be `ToTraceString()` and not `ToSqlString()`.

Answer (score 0):

For queries you can try using .ToString() or .ToSqlString() (depending on whether you are using ObjectQuery or DbQuery), e.g.:

var sql = db.Entities.ToString()

where db is an DbContext instance. In case db was an ObjectContext instance you would use `.ToTraceString()`.

For updates it is not possible to access this information. When debugging you could use IntelliTrace to see commands sent to the database. If you need to trace/log you could use [EF Tracing provider](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/EFProviderWrappers-c0b88f32). There are some tricks needed to make it work with CodeFirst. I [blogged](http://blog.3d-logic.com/2012/03/31/using-tracing-and-caching-provider-wrappers-with-codefirst/) about this some time ago.

Comment: In EF Core I would write this in the DbContext: 
var sql = this.Database.GenerateCreateScript();